# Using neo4j to manage biological tests in clinical trials

Tags: neo4j

I’m new to neo4j but I’m intrigued by the it’s ability to relate events in temporal space. I’m in the pharmaceutical industry and was wondering if that such system/database is being used for managing information in a trial and data that is produced in one throughout various time points.

Looking forward to see any use-cases or hear the thoughts of the community.

Comment: I know that several companies are using Neo4J for specifically this, but I can't give you details. I would recommend asking this question in the Neo4J discord instead if you want a more straight answer https://discord.gg/XFzTHrMs

Comment: Thank you Simon, will ask that question there.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you want to look at event-based patient or trial journeys.
There are some articles out there, but obviously not much since the data is hard to get:

https://medium.com/neo4j/modeling-patient-journeys-with-neo4j-d0785fbbf5a2
https://medium.com/neo4j/lets-write-a-stored-procedure-in-neo4j-part-i-155ad08bad80

There is also a public neo4j db that imports various clinical trials, which is available at:

https://healthecco.org/covidgraph/